# javascript repeat event function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try use this combination of function and repeat with setinterval , and add one unit in each time as i use in this script i create :

```js
        function rot(num) {
          var hide = num - 1;
          jQuery("#ss" + hide).hide(1000);
          jQuery("#ss" + num).show(1000);
          var_end = num + 1;
        }
        var ini = 1;
        setInterval(function() {
          if (end == "") {
            rot(ini);
          } else {
            rot(end);
          }
        }, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="ss1" style="display:none;">yy</div>
<div id="ss2" style="display:none;">yy</div>
```

Each 5 seconds repeat and sen the number 1 for open div with number 1 and after this detect new number add 1 and hide until div and show the div with number 2 , i try many times but i don´t know why don´t want works , howewer don´t send value to function i don´t know

Comment: check the developer console for errors

Comment: `end` is never defined

Comment: you should check your codes dude in creating a variable it should be like this `var myvar`

Comment: what is end in setinterval

Comment: Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/r38q82y3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forget to declare variables

```
<script>
    var end = "";
    var ini = 1;
    function rot(num)
    {
        var hide= num - 1;
        jQuery("#ss"+hide).hide(1000);
        jQuery("#ss"+num).show(1000);
        end = num + 1;
    }

    setInterval(function(){ 
        if (end == "") {
            rot(ini);
        } else {
            rot(end);
        }
    },5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes the problem ose vars in the start, thank´s for your great help with me